# How to fork only with a specific child?

Tags: c, fork

I am trying to build a process tree like this:

```
               P1
            /      \
          P3        P2
                      \
                       P4
                        \
                         ....
```

But i couldn't make it work. I tried this but it only forks with P1.

```
for(int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
    int _pid = fork();
    if(_pid == 0) {
        printf("[son] pid %d from [parent] pid %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
        exit(0);
    }
}
wait(NULL);
```

Comment: Is there a good reason you put "P3" on the left and "P2" on the right in your drawing? Is there any difference between them, and even if there was, a parent-child process relationship knows no left and right, does it? Also, is the desired amount of processes known at compilation time or at run time?

Comment: Initial parent forks twice.  Only one of the children forks more. What's the problem?

Comment: The tree supposed to go from the first created child. There is no difference between them. I am not sure about your last question, P2 and P3 are at depth level 1 and P4 at depth level 2 and so on. And depth is determined by command line arguments. By the way, i can only use one fork call in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement to use only one `fork` call makes the solution cumbersome and ugly, but still doable like this:

Step 1: create an inner loop that will run twice if `i` is 0, and once for any `i > 0`.

Step 2: fork only in the child process after the first iteration of the outer loop.

Step 3: exit the child that was forked on the second iteration of the inner loop.

```
int cur_pid = 0;

printf("Root PID %d started by %d\n", getpid(), getppid());

for (int i = 0; i < depth && cur_pid == 0; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < (i ? 1 : 2); j++) {
        cur_pid = fork();
        if (cur_pid == 0) {
            printf("[son] pid %d from [parent] pid %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
            if (j == 1) {
                exit(0);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } else if (cur_pid < 0) {
            printf("Error forking at PID %d\n", getpid());
        }
    }
}

wait(NULL);
```

Remember to `wait` on the child process of every iteration if you want `getppid` to return valid values!

Comment: You probably don't want to call `exit` there. That will run any exit handlers the process may have. It's a serious mistake to let a process' exit handlers run more than once and there's no reason to think the parent isn't going to run them. (Imagine if there's some stdio buffers that aren't flushed.) Use `_exit`.

Comment: It works fine but doesn't it kill the P3(in the drawing) process? How can i do it without killing it?

Comment: @vignerd I put `exit(0)` there as a place holder, as per your example. Replace it with something else, like `sleep` or infinite loop, or whatever you want the process to actually do. I assume you want more that just create a bunch of processes that do nothing.

Comment: To clarify: in step 3, you don't have to exit, just don't continue with the main loop,